# Angular Cli - How do I rebuild my project

Tags: angular-cli

How do I rebuild my project in Angular.  I build it first with ng build, yet cannot perform that command again as it wont let me change the folder.

I get this error message :
EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat

Is there another command such as ng build update ?

Comment: I had a similar problem with Nativescript + Angular2. As they all use somehow npm it might help to clear its cache `npm cache clean` as described here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10826#issuecomment-165124144

Answer (score 7):

You can delete the output path before the build with:

```
ng build --delete-output-path
```

You can also use one of the alias such as:

```
ng build --deleteOutputPath
```

or

```
ng build -dop
```

Tested with Angular CLI 1.6.5 and Angular 5.2.1

Comment: None of these are working as of Mar 2023. I used `ng cache clean` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem in a Windows machine. You need admin privileges to run that command in Windows. Launch command prompt as administrator and rerun the command. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

every time I've run across this error in Windows, running in an admin command line window, it's because some process has locked the '/dist' folder, which prevents the build process from wiping it then writing new files.

restarting your computer should take care of the problem, but that's a pain - try using something like [Unlocker](https://unlocker.en.softonic.com) to wrestle permissions back from whatever's getting in the way.